# Process Id's and process names

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I'm creating a windows program that basically scans the system to see if a particular process is running or not. I have the process name (AcroRd32.exe) and nothing else.

From what I've read the easiest way to create a snapshot of all processes using **CreateToolhelp32Snapshot** and then iterate through each process looking for the process name.

My application is highly performance centric. So is there a better more efficient way to do this.
The application collects a snapshot every few seconds. Iterating through 100's of processes in the snapshot doesn't seem efficient. Is there a direct API that can find the Process through its process name (and retrieve process handle or id through the name)?

I've searched extensively without much luck. Has anyone tried this before?

Comment: What if there are multiple processes having the same name then?

Comment: I plan to keep track of the Process id's to differentiate different processes with the same name

Comment: Yep, then you might have to loop over all processes yourself and find out those handles with the same name.

Comment: is the snapshot actually a list or could you binary search it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest way to scan for processes is via NTDLL's NtQuerySystemInformation call.  It provides you with a list of names and process IDs of all processes on the system with a single call (or more in rare cases, i.e. large # of processes).  You can combine NtQuerySystemInformation and use a hash to do string comparisons instead of comparing each byte.

```
// headers @ http://pastebin.com/HWzJYpbv


NtQuerySystemInformation = (_RT_NAPI_QUERYSYSINFO)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("NTDLL.DLL"), "NtQuerySystemInformation");

    // Get process information buffer
    do {
        // Allocate buffer for process info
        pBuffer = HeapAlloc(hHeap, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, cbBuffer); 
        if (pBuffer == NULL) {
            // Cannot allocate enough memory for buffer (CRITICAL ERROR)
            return 1;
        }

        // Obtain system process snapshot
        Status = NtQuerySystemInformation(5, pBuffer, cbBuffer, NULL);

        // Allocate bigger buffer for moar data
        if (Status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH) {
            HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pBuffer);
            cbBuffer *= 2; // Increase the size of the buffer :-)
        } else if ((Status) != 0x00) {
            // Can't query process information (probably rootkit or anti-virus)
            HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pBuffer);
            return 1;
        }
    } while (Status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);

    // Get pointer to first system process info structure
    pInfo = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION)pBuffer;

    // Loop over each process
    for (;;) {
        // Get process name
        pszProcessName = pInfo->ImageName.Buffer;

        // ... do work. For a fast string compare, calculate a 32-bit hash of the string, then compare to a static hash.
        if(CRC32(pszProcessName) == 0xDEADBEEF /* <- hash of adobe reader process name goez here */) {
            // Found process
        }

        // Load next entry
        if (pInfo->NextEntryOffset == 0)
            break;
        pInfo = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION)(((PUCHAR)pInfo)+ pInfo->NextEntryOffset);
    }
```

**Tested on Windows 2000 - Windows 7 English editions, x64/x86 (except Win XP x64)**
Note: It will return all processes to 32-bit WOW64 processes on 64-bit systems.

Comment: `CRC32` of a string isn't faster than `strcmp` or especially `memcmp` against another string.  Most will early-out in the first 16-byte chunk (one SSE2 vector) even if they're longer.  CRC32 has to look at each byte separately as well, and do more work for each byte.  (Unless its optimized with hardware CRC32C instructions or fancy SIMD tricks, but `memcmp` is normally optimized with SIMD only requiring SSE2, baseline for x86-64.  Best case is if you can pass a constant size that's a multiple of 16, or at least 8.)

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

Each process has a **unique ID** but **not unique name**. There could be multiple processes with the same name. So it is impossible to get the process handle out of its name directly without iterating over all processes.

Internally all prcesses are linked together somehow, e.g., in a linked list. Even if there was a function `GetProcessByName()` provided, it would internally traverse the list to find those processes with that name on behalf of you as well. So that won't make a big difference in performance.

**Aside**

Give a shot to `EnumProcesses()` which has less overhead and is simpler. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021307/enumprocesses-vs-createtoolhelp32snapshot).

```
BOOL WINAPI EnumProcesses(
  __out  DWORD *pProcessIds,
  __in   DWORD cb,
  __out  DWORD *pBytesReturned
);
```

MSDN has an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682623.aspx) for this.

Comment: In fact, there will be multiple processes with the name 'svchost.exe' on Windows; they vary by what user they're running as.

Comment: Yep, there're quite a few examples on Windows I've met before.