# Windows DLL injector in C doesn't inject the DLL

Tags: c, dll-injection

I am trying to write a DLL injector to perform a DLL injector on a calculator process.

I wrote the DLL injector program in C and the DLL but the injector dosent inject the DLL or any other DLL (I tried to take some random windows DLL that the calculator doesn't use).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    LPCSTR dllpath = "C:\\Users\\......\\Dll1.dll";
    printf("#### Starting ####\n");

    printf("step 1: attaching the target process memory\n");
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( 
        PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 
        FALSE, 
        6456 // target process id
    );
    if (hProcess != NULL) {
        printf("step 2: allocate the target memory process\n");
        LPVOID dllPathMemoryAddr = VirtualAllocEx(
            hProcess, 
            NULL, 
            strlen(dllpath), 
            MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, 
            PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE 
        );
        if (dllPathMemoryAddr != NULL) {
            printf("step 3: write to the process memory\n");
            BOOL succeededWriting = WriteProcessMemory(
                hProcess, 
                dllPathMemoryAddr,  
                dllpath, 
                strlen(dllpath), 
                NULL 
            );

            if (succeededWriting) {
                printf("step 4: execute.\n");
                FARPROC loadLibAddr = GetProcAddress(
                    GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll")),
                    "LoadLibraryA" 
                );
                HANDLE rThread = CreateRemoteThread( 
                    hProcess, 
                    NULL, 
                    0, 
                     (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)loadLibAddr,
                    dllPathMemoryAddr,
                    0,
                    NULL
                );
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

after running the injector I get this output:

```
#### Starting ####
step 1: attaching the target process memory
step 2: allocate the target memory process
step 3: write to the process memory
step 4: execute.
```

after that, I am still unable to see in process explorer the new DLL.

Comment: How do you know that `LoadLibrary` has the same address in the remote process that it does in yours? What is the return/error code from `CreateRemoteThread` ?

Comment: Tip: `main` should return `0` for success. (Well, technically `EXIT_SUCCESS`.) I doubt that `TRUE` is `0`.

Comment: The ```CreateRemoteThread``` return NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I compiled the DLL as 64 but accidentally compiled the DLL injector has complied as 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling GetProcAddress() to get the address of LoadLibraryA(), this is returning the address of LoadLibraryA in your local process not the injected one.  This is not guaranteed to be correct in the external process.  You do not need to get the address manually, CreateRemoteThread will resolve the address for you.

Here is a very simple injector example that will explain how to do it

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

DWORD GetPid(char * targetProcess)
{
    HANDLE snap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (snap && snap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32 pe;
        pe.dwSize = sizeof(pe);
        if (Process32First(snap, &pe))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_stricmp(pe.szExeFile, targetProcess))
                {
                    CloseHandle(snap);
                    return pe.th32ProcessID;
                }
            } while (Process32Next(snap, &pe));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char * dllpath = "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\dll.dll";
    char * processToInject = "csgo.exe";
    long pid = 0;
    while (!pid)
    {
        pid = GetPid(processToInject);
        Sleep(10);
    }

    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, pid);
    if (hProc && hProc != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
            void * loc = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, 0, MAX_PATH, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
            WriteProcessMemory(hProc, loc, dllpath, strlen(dllpath) + 1, 0);       
            HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProc, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibraryA, loc, 0, 0);
            CloseHandle(hThread);
    }

    CloseHandle(hProc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For what its worth, here is Microsoft documentation on using the Tool Help Functions, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/using-the-tool-help-functions which has several topics with source code using `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`. And see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021307/enumprocesses-vs-createtoolhelp32snapshot whose discussions and postings indicate other ways to enumerate over processes.

Comment: OS does not want to allocate physical memory for the second copy of kernel32.dll because that would be a waste of resources. Then, it will use the same physical memory.

Comment: @GiladDiCastro Your code doesn't work, mine does.  Does it solve your problem or not?

Comment: It dident sovle the problem.

Comment: @GiladDiCastro what is the problem? Are you running as administrator?  Use the visual studio debugger and GetLastError() to give us more information on the problem